# Wrong number of segments - auth0 token

Tags: laravel, authentication, auth0

I've implemented authentication through auth0 on my laravel application, the login works fine and it returns a token and user details, here is the code for the login:

```
            $auth0Response = $guzzle->post('myauthurl/token', [
            'header' => [
                "content-type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type'=> "password",
                "username"=>trim($data["username"]),
                "password"=>trim($data["password"]),
                "client_id"=>"myclient_secret",
                "client_secret"=>"secret",
                "audience"=>"https://myurl.auth0.com/userinfo"
            ]
        ]);

        $auth0ResponseBody = json_decode($auth0Response->getBody(),true);
        $additionalDetails = $this->getUserDetails(trim($data["username"]));
        $userDetails = array_merge($auth0ResponseBody,$additionalDetails);
```

but when I get the token from the response, pass it on my request headers and try to access a protected route, I get an error with message 'Wrong number of segments

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "Wrong number of segments",
    "statusCode": 401
}
```

}

Comment: How do you pass the token from header?

Comment: I'm using postman, I add it under the authorization tab, and it gets added to the headers authomatically

Comment: How do you validate the token? Is the token that you get from Auth0 a JWT? My blind guess is that you get an opaque token, but then try to use it as a JWT. Can you post examples of concrete Authorization headers that you send to a protected route?

Comment: these are my headers
{ content-type: application/jston, accept:application/json, token: bearer the actual token}

what do you mean by 'validate the token', the auth0 documentation doesn't say anything about validation the returned token, or maybe I need to revisit the docs

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski did you get my reply toy our question ?